# CakePHP How to create pagination from API JSON data source

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-4.x

I have an API like [example](https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all)

I have used cakephp HTTP client to get data, below my attempted code

```
public index()
{
    $http = new Client();
    $response = $http->get('https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all');
    // $json = $response->getJson();  //also tried usgin json
    $countries = $this->paginate($response);
    $this->set(compact('countries '));
}
```

I am trying to apply pagination with this country data then fetch it in view with pagination.
After tried above code , I have gotten below error

*Argument 1 passed to Cake\Datasource\Paginator::extractData() must be an instance of Cake\Datasource\RepositoryInterface, instance of Cake\Http\Client\Response given, called in \myapp\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Datasource\Paginator.php on line 176*

How can I get my desire result ?

Answer (score 1):

You have probably need to implement a class who extend RepositoryInterface.

```
class JsonSource implements Cake\Datasource\RepositoryInterface 
{ ... }

public index() {
  $http = new Client();
  $response = $http->get('https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all');

  $src = new JsonSource();
  $src->fromResponse($response);

  $countries = $this->paginate($src);
  $this->set(compact('countries ')); }
```

Is a bit tedious, because you need to define Json like a datasource.

Answer (score 1):

The default pagination only supports querying tables (repositories), or operating on pre-built query instances.

To extend on **[@Zeppi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63699636/1392379)**. You basically have three somewhat straightforward options here:

1. Create custom query/repository implementations as hinted by @Zeppi.

   This can indeed be quite a lot of work though, so you might want to look into alternatively implementing it with the help of plugins, for example **[muffin/webservice](https://github.com/UseMuffin/Webservice)**, which does most of the hard work of implementing the required interfaces.
2. Or create a [**custom paginator**](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/controllers/components/pagination.html#simple-pagination) that actually accepts and works on array data.
3. Or use what is widely know as a "datatable", that is a JavaScript based table in the frontend that paginates the data, for example **[jQuery DataTables](https://datatables.net)**.